# frontend application in java

Tags: java, wpf

can we develop java frontend application just like we do in WPF? that runs on windows platform?

Comment: and why did you tag all languages?

Comment: Please stop spamming tags that don't apply to your questions.

Comment: Came to answer wpf... not wpf... sad face :( if you are talking about a client side app that is non Microsoft, you could write in flex, and host it on the Adobe air platform.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, just use [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/).

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use java also for frontend applications, those applications will require the java VM and will probably run in some platforms not only windows, this in general then depends on the details of your specific application.

Said so, I am not aware of libraries available in the Java world which would let you compose rich and advanced user interface like you can do with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Java can be used to create front-end applications that run not only on Windows, but on any operating system that has Java installed on it.

To create front-end GUIs, you could use either AWT(very old, not recommended), Swing or SWT(the latest addition to the Java GUI library by IBM).

Answer (score 0):

[XUI](http://www.xoetrope.com/xui) is an XML-based frontend development toolset for Java.

If you're looking for a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) equivalent, [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html) would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several GUI toolkits out there (as already mentioned by others), but they only provide the basic building blocks. (WPF also falls in this category, AFAIK.)

I recommend to build GUI application on top of a modular Rich Client Platform (RCP) such as the NetBeans Platform (Swing-based) or Eclipse RCP (SWT-based).

Here some links for the NetBeans Platform:

http://platform.netbeans.org/

http://netbeans.org/features/platform/features.html

http://netbeans.org/features/platform/all-docs.html

Answer (score 0):

There´s a technology for desktop frontends from ADOBE called Adobe AIR.
It´s similar to WPF (it uses a variation of XML, in this case MXML), and has several rich components and effects!

Try it out at http://get.adobe.com/air/